# nRF52840 dongle Client and Server Coexistence

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, client, gatt, nrf52

I am using a nRF52840 dongle for a BLE-based project. Is there a possibility that the dongle could work as both Client and Server?

That is, I would like the node to advertise and connect to a mobile phone and collect data first. After collecting the data, I need the dongle to send the data to another server that is advertising. The second server is also a nRF52840 dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes nRF52840 can have multiple roles. Either one at a time or simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am puzzled how that can be done in the dongle. Would you share any references I can use?

Comment: @AjeethChandrasekaran take a look at the [LE Secure Connections Multirole Example](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/sdk_nrf5_v17.0.2/ble_sdk_app_multirole_lesc.html)

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Thank you for the response. I will check it out.